# How to update all nested documents of an array in a selected document in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

In a situation I need to update a field of all documents nested in an array in Mongoose model.

I add a new nested document of uploaded image to Users collection and I need to set "is_available" of all previous documents to be false and only "is_available" field of newly inserted document to be true.

All I searched and found was about updating a nested document with specific id or filter. but I didn't find a way to update a specific field of all nested documents of an array in a Model.

My Model:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UsersSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, default: "" },
  lastname: { type: String, default: "" },
  images: [{
    dir: { type: String },
    is_available: { type: Boolean }
  }]
});

var Users = mongoose.model("Users", UsersSchema, "users");
module.exports = Users;
```

Actual result:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ce950aa4sw435ty503ab83b"), 
    "name" : "Sina", 
    "image" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5cf4dd3da6b4gb6bcf9c6dc1"), 
            "dir" : "profiledirectory/804eafeaf8acc40a3d6.jpg", 
            "is_available" : true
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5cf4fffs2419316bddffgg82"), 
            "dir" : "profiledirectory/d85b01ac40fa6b1a7c1.jpg", 
            "is_available" : true
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5cf4ff334fhd316bef2fdt40"), 
            "dir" : "profiledirectory/512d9d19da7a4322b37.jpg", 
            "is_available" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected Result:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ce950aa4sw435ty503ab83b"), 
    "name" : "Sina", 
    "image" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5cf4dd3da6b4gb6bcf9c6dc1"), 
            "dir" : "profiledirectory/804eafeaf8acc40a3d6.jpg", 
            "is_available" : false
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5cf4fffs2419316bddffgg82"), 
            "dir" : "profiledirectory/d85b01ac40fa6b1a7c1.jpg", 
            "is_available" : false
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5cf4ff334fhd316bef2fdt40"), 
            "dir" : "profiledirectory/512d9d19da7a4322b37.jpg", 
            "is_available" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

```
Code Snippet:

let updateQuery = {
  $set: { 'image.$.is_available': false },
  $push: {
    image: [
      {
        dir: "profiledirectory/558bb6938ecd54bde556af122a4.jpg",
        is_available: true
      }
    ]
  }
}


let findQuery = { _id: req.body.user_id }

Users.findOneAndUpdate(findQuery,
  updateQuery, function (err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err.message)
    } else {
      res.send('successful')
    }
  })
```

Comment: what query you have tried ?

Comment: i updated my question and added code snippet

Comment: is my answer working ?

Comment: @SaurabhMistry I combined your answer with @mourya venkat aswer.
`user.save((err,updated)…` didn't work for me I used `eventObject.findOneAndUpdate(...` for that part.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what you've mentioned, you keep adding objects to image field dynamically, and each time you add the new object, the existing objects should be overridden with **is_available:false**

```
    eventObject.find(query).lean().exec(function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
            logger.error(err);
            return reject(err.message)
        }
        // Assuming there will be only one record based on the query you make
        if(response.length>0){
            response[0].images = response.images.map((image)=>{
                image.is_available = false
                return image
            })

            // Now append your new image to the modified response
            response[0].images.push(newimage)// this should be the newImage object
            // Now use findOneAndUpdate to update the existing doc by querying with id or according to your usecase

            eventObject.findOneAndUpdate(query, response[0], { upsert: true }, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err)
            }
            logger.info(data);
            return resolve(newData);
        })
        }
    })
```

So the basic approach is,

1. Get the doc from the DB
2. Update the content of the doc
3. Add the new data
4. update the record with updated data.

Answer (score 0):

after you uploaded file , you have to find user

```
  // after upload image 

  User.findOne({_id:req.user._id}).lean().exec((err,user)=>{
        if(!err && user){
              // setting all previous images to false 
              user.image.forEach(image=>{
                    image.is_available=false;
              });
              // now pushing new uploded item to image array
        let newImage={"dir" : "path of uploaded item here"  , "is_available" : true};

              user.image.push(newImage);
              user.save((err,updated)=>{
                   if(!err && updated){ 
                     return res.status(200).json({status:"success",message:"User updated"});
                   }
              });
        }
  });
```